# Why INL is not a sum of previos DNL

Tags: adc

In the ADC I have 2 bit system and Vref=1V with actual voltage shown as shown bellow.
I have transformed the actual into UNIFORM as shown bellow and i produced INL from it.
Bu when i started to calculate the DNL by the definition i see that the DNL's are far from following the rule of
INL(N)=DNL(0)+DNL(1)..+DNL(N-1)
Where did i go wrong?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Guess you find a good declaration of DNL and INL in TI's Classic: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa013/slaa013.pdf- at page 11: "The name integral nonlinearity derives from the fact that the summation of the differential nonlinearities from the bottom up to a particular step, determines the value of the integral nonlinearity at that step."

Comment: yes and i dont see it in my ADC calculation

Comment: Well your INL Column simply is not the summation of the differential nonlinearities from the bottom up to a particular step. 0 + -0,3 is simply not -0,0667